# Should I use 'try-catch' or 'if-else' when writing a unique field to DB?

Tags: mysql, database, exception, web

In my app, I need to generate a random string and write to a unique key field in a DB table.
I wonder which approach is better:

1. Just write, and catch the key conflict exception generated by DB, and retry.
2. Query the table with the new string, and if it is present, try another.

Since the field is a unique key, with index built, a query in 2 doesn't cost much, but the query is always there, no matter how rare the conflict is.

Is there anything else to consider? What is the standard practice here?

Comment: Generating a random string by appending the DateTime as Long. It reduces the effort of checking the value for Unique.

Comment: @SantronManibharathi The random string is a verification code with 6-8 chars for user to enter. I intend to keep it short and not try hard to avoid conflict.

Comment: Then the first method suits better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under most circumstances, I would suggest trying to write your value and handle the key conflict if it occurs.  This approach only requires one request to the database under the normal happy-path.  Additionally, it is possible (although perhaps unlikely) that another process may insert the conflicting value between the time you query for its existence and the time you insert it.  The first approach would prevent that problem.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about the race condition, it requires a lock if I take the 2nd approach. I will just trigger the exception then. Thanks!